# Android Camera, Gallery and Mail Handling

Tags: android, email, email-attachments

I am working on an android project where I click picture from camera or pick from gallery and I need to send that image as an attachment in a mail. Here's my code for getting picture from camera `enter code here`

```
public void launchCamera(View view){
    gallery.setEnabled(false);
    String fileName = "abc.jpg";
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION," XYZ");
    imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
    Intent intent =new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);

    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
}
```

Here is the code to get Image from Gallery

```
public void launchGallery(View view){
    cameraButton.setEnabled(false);
    Intent intent = new Intent(
        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent,PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
```

Here is the onActivityResult function

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String imageId = convertImageUriToFile( imageUri,CameraActivity);
    }
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        Uri uri = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        filep = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
    }
}
public  String convertImageUriToFile ( Uri imageUri, Activity activity ) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    int imageID = 0;

    try {
        /*********** Which columns values want to get *******/
        String[] proj = {
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION
        };

        cursor = getContentResolver().query(imageUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
        int columnIndexThumb = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);
        int file_ColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);

        int thumbID = 0;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            imageID = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
            thumbID = cursor.getInt(columnIndexThumb);
            filep = cursor.getString(file_ColumnIndex);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    return filep;
}
```

The code for sending email is

```
public class SendMail
{
    private Context context;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    public void sending(String filepath, String rec, String bod)
    {
        // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
        String to = rec;

        // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
        final String from = "abc@gmail.com";
        // final String username = "xyz";
        final String pass = "qwerty";
        // Assuming you are sending email from localhost
        String host = "smtp.gmail.com";

        // Get system properties
        Properties properties = System.getProperties();

        // Setup mail server
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(from, pass);
            }
        });

        try{

            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                new InternetAddress(to));
            message.setSubject("Plant Trees");

            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.setText(bod);

            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // Part two is attachment
            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filepath);
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            messageBodyPart.setFileName(filepath);
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
            mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
            mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
            mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
            mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
            mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content- handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");

            message.setContent(multipart);

            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
        }catch (MessagingException mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And the code to call the sending function in main activity is

```
public void sem()
{
    SendMail sm=new SendMail();

    sm.sending(filep,"abc@gmail.com","xyz");
}
```

When I am running this as soon as I tap the send button the app crashes
Please help also sorry for the mistakes and large code size but I have just learnt Android and this is my first project. Thanks in Advance

Comment: You have posted a lot of code but you did not seem to post the code where the problem is. You probably need to show the on the onClick method for your button and how you are setting it up.

Comment: Sorry sir, but I figured out the camera and pick gallery issue and have updated the post accordingly. Just want to know if the way I am sending the mail is right or not. sem() is the function which is called when send button is tapped.